# TIBCO SPOTFIRE 7.5-How to set a document property with checkbox values

Tags: spotfire

In TIBCO SPOTFIRE 7.5 I have a problem to set a document property with values selected in a checkbox: I have to use "OR" clause  between 2 checkbox filter (it works always in "AND") so I want to set 2 document properties with checked values (2 checkbox) and use them in a limit expression.

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Comment: What are the names of your document properties and the respective columns you want them filtered on? Where are you trying to filter these (cross table, bar chart, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

I will list two possible answers here, that differ in complexity. Which solution to use depends on how strong your requirements are on what UI control you can use.

#### Option 1 - Use Property Control

Add two property controls to a text area to set the document properties that will be used to limit data. Each property control will be set up to select values from a column in your data, for instance like this with the Film example data:
[image]

With two property controls as the one above, add a data limit expression to the visualization (Visualization properties -> Data -> Limit data using expression). Set expression like this:

```
[Actor] = "${Actor}" OR [Actress] = "${Actress}"
```

Here I've used the column [Actor] to match the value of the document property Actor or the column [Actress] to match the value of document property Actress.

#### Option 2 - Use JavaScript

If you really need the UI to be a checkbox, then there is no Spotfire Control to handle that. If the choices you need to allow the user to make is static, then this option is fairly straightforward. If you need the option to be based on the data, then it takes more work.

Let's start with the static case. In a textarea, add an input field and then modify the html to something similar to this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="check1"> Checkbox1</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="check2"> Checkbox2</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="check3"> Checkbox3</label><br>

<div id='mySpotfireControl' style='display:none'>
  <SpotfireControl id="344f7da2bc5d4baca88c7e76cb7d429b" />
</div>
```

Also add a javascript to the text area, similar to this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var jsValue = $(this).val();
  $('#mySpotfireControl input').val(jsValue).blur()
})
```

This will move the value from the checkbox into the Spotfire Document Property. From there, you can add a limiting expression same as when using solution 1 above.

If you need to generate the set of checkboxes that are available, then you need to generate the html for the text area dynamically. You can do this by writing an IronPython script that inspects the current data, and creates the html for the text area. This IronPython script would need to be invoced somehow, if you want it fully automatic you can trigger it from a data function that runs when the analysis is opened.

Comment: Thank you, but in this way I have to use a List box and not a Check box. My client requiremet is to use a check box...

Comment: @GraziaPalmisano - I have added a description of how you could use checkboxes with the help of some javascript. I hope that can work for you. Let me know if you need me to elaborate on some point.